# Is it possible to make a SVG path block click actions?

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, svg

I'm trying to implement an overlay/highlight tutorial, requirements are that it should be able to highlight several elements at the same time. So I found out that working with SVG Paths worked well to generate a grayed out area and only keep the important highlighted elements on view and able to be clicked.

Now what I'm trying to achieve is to block the user whenever he tries to click on the grayed out area. Already tried pointer-events="unset" inside the path but didn't work.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCTps.png) for an easier reference.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Try `pointer-events:none` since the `unset` keyword resets a property to its inherited value

Comment: @enxaneta thanks for answering, but sadly it didn't work either

Comment: In this case you should consider to add a code example to your question